# I need some arrangement of 12 divs. I can use HTML, CSS. I will show the code and the arrangement

Tags: html, css, web

I need specific arrangement of 12 divs. I'm trying but I can't. I will show our the code and the arrangement. If you can please help me.

The arrangement of 12 divs:

[image: the arrangement of 12 divs]

I gave them percents of width and height but it not work.
I will show the code.

My code:

```css
.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.gallery div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px !important;
  float: left;
}

.one {
  width: 21.42%;
  height: 25% ;
  display: inline-block;
}

.two {
  width: 14.28%;
  height: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tree {
  width: 64.26%;
  height: 37.5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fore {
  width: 14.28%;
  height: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.five {
  width: 14.28%;
  height: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.six {
  width: 7.14%;
  height: 37.5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.seven {
  width: 21.42%;
  height: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.eight {
  width: 14.28%;
  height: 65.5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nine {
  width: 28.56%;
  height: 37.5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ten {
  width: 14.28%;
  height: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.eleven {
  width: 28.56%;
  height: 37.5%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.twelve {
  width: 28.56%;
  height: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container gallery">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="tree"></div>
  <div class="fore"></div>
  <div class="five"></div>
  <div class="six"></div>
  <div class="seven"></div>
  <div class="eight"></div>
  <div class="nine"></div>
  <div class="ten"></div>
  <div class="eleven"></div>
  <div class="twelve"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isneezy/ves9n6nj/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container gallery">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="tree"></div>
  <div class="fore"></div>
  <div class="five"></div>
  <div class="six"></div>
  <div class="seven"></div>
  <div class="eight"></div>
  <div class="nine"></div>
  <div class="ten"></div>
  <div class="eleven"></div>
  <div class="twelve"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, .container
{
    height: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0
}

.one {
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% * 3) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 2) / 8);
    background-color: red;
}

.two{
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% * 2) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 2) / 8);
    background-color: green;
}

.tree{
    float: right;
    width: calc((100% * 9) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 3) / 8);
    background-color: blue;
}

.fore{
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% * 2) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 4) / 8);
    background-color: blue;
}

.five{
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% * 2) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 2) / 8);
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0
}

.six{
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% * 2) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 6) / 8);
    background-color: yellow;
}

.seven{
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% * 1) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 3) / 8);
    background-color: brown;
}

.eight{
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% * 3) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 2) / 8);
    background-color: cyan;
}

.nine{
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% * 4) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 3) / 8);
    background-color: magenta;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: calc((100% * 4) / 14);
}

.ten{
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% * 2) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 5) / 8);
    background-color: purple;
}

.ten{
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% * 2) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 5) / 8);
    background-color: purple;
}

.eleven{
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% * 4) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 3) / 8);
    background-color: gray;
}

.twelve{
    float: left;
    width: calc((100% * 4) / 14);
    height: calc((100% * 2) / 8);
    background-color: teal;
}
```

**UPDATE**

The code above is 100% responsive this means it will look great at any browser or screen size

Answer (score 1):

It's not the most performant, but in the case of this puzzle, I would recommend using absolute positioning. That would be the easiest by far. It's also possible floating the elements, but it will be quite a challenge in this case.

Solving the puzzle by using position: absolute;

**HTML: stays the same**

**CSS:**

```
.gallery {
  /* Use the gallery div as a container for the absolute children. The children's top/left/bottom/right will be based on this div */
  position: relative;
  /* Let's assume each box in the raster is 10x10px */
  width: 140px;
  height: 80px;
}
.gallery > div {
  position: absolute;
}
.one {
  /* Since every child-div is absolute, you can use top/left/bottom/right */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 30px;
}
.two {
  top: 0;
  left: 30px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
/* add height/width/top/left for all other children */
```

It is possible to use % values as well, but I thought 10px was easier to explain.

Comment: thanks. I think it will help. but I have to use this gallery Div width:100% and height 800px. so I will try to make it as you sad but in my case. Thanks again.